# Ассемблер на Win10 x64 без MS DOS

Tags: ассемблер, windows-10, masm, tasm

Я нашел кучу ссылок компиляции ассемблера на Win10 x64 **c** MS DOS. Можно ли компилировать и запускать без MS DOS? Или хотя бы сделать так, чтоб полученный exe запускался на чистой Win10 x64?

Comment: Просто ищите примеры программ для windows - будет компилироваться работать и на 32-битных, и на 64-битных системах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Только ваши программы должны использовать не прерывания DOS, а функции WinAPI или функции Сишного рантайма и оперировать более широкими регистрами.

**hello.asm**

```
global WinMain
extern ExitProcess
extern MessageBoxA

section .data 

title:  db 'Win x64 example', 0
msg:    db 'Hello World!', 0


section .text

WinMain:
    sub rsp, 28h  
    mov rcx, 0
    lea rdx, [msg]
    lea r8, [title]
    mov r9d, 0
    call MessageBoxA
    add rsp, 28h  

    mov  ecx, eax
    call ExitProcess

    hlt
```

Компилируем

```
yasm -fwin64 hello.asm
```

Линкуем

```
ld -o hello.exe hello.obj -luser32 -lkernel32
```